# Running arbitrary strings as Dart code in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, runtime

How can this be achieved?

For example a file contains a dart function, how could the flutter app run this function if it was not originally compiled? [This blog](https://iiro.dev/2019/08/15/how-to-eval-in-dart/) shows that it is possible using `Uri.dataFromString` and isolates as long as a Flutter app is still in debug mode but I want to make it work in a released Flutter app.

```dart
void main() async {
  // I filled out the content of these variables here
  // for clarity. In a real scenario, you'd probably
  // parse these from somewhere.
  final packageUri = 'package:magic/magic_sauce.dart';
  final functionName = 'applyMagicSauce';
  final input = 'Hellooooooo from the other side!';
  final uri = Uri.dataFromString(
    '''
    import "dart:isolate";
    import '$packageUri';

    void main(_, SendPort port) {
      port.send($functionName("$input"));
    }
    ''',
    mimeType: 'application/dart',
  );

  final port = ReceivePort();
  final isolate =
  await Isolate.spawnUri(uri, [], port.sendPort);
  final String response = await port.first;

  port.close();
  isolate.kill();

  print(response);
}
```

NB: I know that this is extremely unsafe for the app security.

Comment: Someone tried to do this for a REPL for dart many moons ago.  I think it will fail now on all tree-shaken AOT VMs, and if it doesn't, it should. :)   EDIT ahh, yes, your referenced blog entry shows that.

Comment: Then is there a way to compile a flutter app within a flutter app?

Comment: As a separate process, yes.  That's essentially what dartpad is doing.

Comment: yes I know https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ but I was wondering if it was possible to embed it myself without their whole package